# How to access the image in django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

The image is not showing in the template how to access all. All my code is below.

> model.py

```
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='todoimages/%Y/%m/%d', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True )
```

> home.html

```
<img class="img-fluid rounded mb-5" src="{{todoItem.image}}" alt="{{todoItem.title}}">
```

> settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images/')
```

Comment: `{{ todoItem.image.url }}`?

Comment: not working I got the error, ValueError at /
The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.